# How I can do break a line in output print python

Tags: python, printing, output, line-breaks

I´m new in Python and I´ve a code that extract cookies from HTTP Headers and this is Ok. But I need break line on output to friendly format.

The output is like this:

```
has_recent_activity=1; path=/; expires=Sat, 31 Aug 2019 16:24:07 -0000,_octo=GH1.1.1398580293.1567265047; domain=.github.com; path=/;expires=Tue,31 Aug 2021 15:24:07 -0000, logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/;expires=Wed, 31 Aug 2039 15:24:07 -0000; secure; HttpOnly"
```

And I need format like this:

```
has_recent_activity=1; path=/, 
Session=GH1.1.1398580293.1567265047; domain=.github.com; path=/,
logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

Break line for each cookie tag

This is my simple code:

```
import urllib2

r = urllib2.Request("https://github.com/carineconstantino/security_tools")

c = urllib2.urlopen(r)

cookies = c.info()['Set-Cookie']

print (cookies)
```

Comment: Your expected output is missing data from the original input. And what defines where the string should be split? And what have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly, you are trying to add line breaks in certain parts of a string you're trying to print.

One approach (although there may perhaps be better ones) would be to swap the

`print(cookies)`

for something along the lines of

`print(cookies.replace('path=/; ', 'path=/;\n'))`

or

`print(cookies.replace('path=/, ', 'path=/,\n'))`

if you prefer the line break after the path=/,

Line breaks in print statements can generally be handled with \n.